# Appending a GROUP BY result into original table

Tags: python, pandas

```
 col = full.groupby('state')[['demVote']].mean()
```

`full` is the name of the original table. How would I append the results of this group by statement on to the original table full as a column called `'DEM'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `transform`:

```
full['DEM'] = full.groupby('state')['demVote'].transform('mean')
```

**For example:**

```
>>> full
   demVote state
0        1    ca
1        2    ca
2        3    ny
3        4    ny

full['DEM'] = full.groupby('state')['demVote'].transform('mean')

>>> full
   demVote state  DEM
0        1    ca  1.5
1        2    ca  1.5
2        3    ny  3.5
3        4    ny  3.5
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work, can you provide a specif example if not?

```
full['DEM'] = full.groupby('state').mean()['demVote']
```